# Python: Schedule a task between two times

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I'm using [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) to automate a few things and would like one task to be executed between two certain hours of day, twice a day. Basically, what I'm looking for, would be a command like:

```py
schedule.between("08:00", "18:00").do(job)
```

Is it possible to create a helper function or similar to make this valid?

Comment: Would it be repetitive running or do you wish run the function once?

Comment: It's a function that should be executed twice a day at a random time between the specified interval.

Comment: I would check out the date time library, it is a core python library that will supply you with the date and or time in almost any format.